# How to completely disable X authentication on boot?

Tags: xorg

I would like to completely disable x authentication on boot.

I know I can edit `/etc/Xn.hosts` for specific hosts, but how to allow all connections (like `xhost +`) be setup on boot?

Comment: Note that listening on TCP network ports is disabled by default for non-ancient X servers. You'll have to remove the `-nolisten tcp` or add `-listen tcp` arguments (depending on your server version), or configure your display manager. Use `ps` to see which options your X server was started with.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 18.04 which takes GDM3 as default. What should I do then?

Comment: Look at the comment in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/34663) for ubuntu 18.04. And this only enables the network socket, you'll still have to deal with the authentication (but not doing this might be a reason why probably anything you tried didn't work). Not sure how to configure it in GDM3, reading the docs for it and looking at the existing configuration file might help (I am not using GDM, so I can't look).